# Сколько в интервале [a; b] - числа, которые делятся на 7 без остатка

Tags: c++, c++14

Напишите программу, которая считывает числа `a`, `b` `(100 <a, b <10000)` из входных данных и определяет, сколько в интервале [a; b] - числа, которые делятся на 7 без остатка. Покажите их на экране и подсчитайте их

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int sum=0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; ++i) {
        if (i % 7 ==0) {
            i++;
            cout << sum << ' ';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i++;` не нужен, `cout << sum << ' ';` замените на `cout << i << ' ';`, добавьте переменную number и ею подсчитывайте числа, после цикла выведите ее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;

    int number = 0;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            number++;
            cout << i << ' ';
        }
    }
    
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "number: " << number << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Ссылка на код, чтобы поиграться: https://ideone.com/ctv16G

Comment: ускорение : `cout << i << ' '; i += 6 ;`

Answer (score 4):

```
int deltaA = (a % 7 == 0)? 0 : (7 - (a % 7));
int count = (b - (b % 7) - (a + deltaA)) / 7 + 1;
if (count < 0)
  count = 0;
```

```js
function bySeven(a, b) {
  var deltaA = (a % 7 == 0)? 0 : (7 - (a % 7));
  var count = (b - (b % 7) - (a + deltaA) ) / 7 + 1;
  return Math.max(count, 0);
}

console.log(bySeven(43, 25));
console.log(bySeven(43, 48));
console.log(bySeven(25, 43));
console.log(bySeven(25, 30));
console.log(bySeven(14, 14));
console.log(bySeven(13, 14));
console.log(bySeven(14, 15));
```

Comment: Вот только по условию надо еще и вывести сами числа. Без цикла всё-таки не обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

Выравниваем `a` на границу, кратную 7, с округлением вверх

```
a = (a + 6) / 7 * 7;
```

Выравниваем `b` на границу, кратную 7, с округлением вниз

```
b = b / 7 * 7;
```

Вычисляем количество чисел, кратных 7, в полученном интервале `[a, b]` (в предположении, что `a <= b`)

```
n = (b - a) / 7 + 1;
```

Comment: Thx man, it's work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
short a, b, c;
int main() {
std::cin >> a >> b;
for(a = a; a <= b; a++) {
if(a % 7 == 0) {
std::cout << a << ' ';
c++;
}
    }
std::cout << std::endl << c;
        }
```

Comment: Вот скриншот работы программы: https://pp.userapi.com/c848520/v848520849/106a9/stCwEaLFG6Y.jpg